# Set up server but browser shows file directory

Tags: apache-2.2

I just set up my server and set up virtual hosts but when I go to the site, it only shows a directory of files. For example, if you go to gomms.co.kr it shows a directory of files. If I go to http://gomms.co.kr/index.php it shows the script. How do I fix this so when I just go to gomms.co.kr it shows the site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the *DirectoryIndex* option in your Apache configuration and extend it with *index.php*:

```
# Old, e.g.:
#DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
# New:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php
```